# crypt(3) causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, crypt

I am trying to make a small program that opens a file, reads every line, hashes that line using the `crypt(3)` algorithm, and then write that back to an output file.

However, whenever I try using the `crypt()` method, it causes a segment fault. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Command I'm using to compile the code:

```
g++ hasher.cpp -o hasher -lcrypt
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream> // User I/O
#include <fstream>  // File I/O
#include <vector>   // String array
#include <cstdlib>  // Exit method
#include <crypt.h>  // Crypt(3)

// Input & Output file names
std::string input_file;
std::string output_file;

// Plaintext & Hashed passwords
std::vector<std::string> passwords;


// Read input and output files
void read_file_names()
{

    std::cout << "Input:  ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input_file);

    std::cout << "Output: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, output_file);
}

// Load passwords from input file
void load_passwords()
{
    // Line / Hash declarations
    std::string line;
    std::string hash;

    // Declare files
    std::ifstream f_input;
    std::ifstream f_output;

    // Open files
    f_input.open(input_file.c_str());


    // Check if file can be opened
    if (!f_input) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open " << input_file << " for reading." << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }

    // Read all lines from file
    while(getline(f_input, line))
    {
        // This line causes a segmentation fault
        // I have no idea why
        hash = crypt(line.c_str(), "");
        std::cout << "Hashed [" << hash << "] " << line << std::endl;
    }
}

// Main entry point of the app
int main()
{
    read_file_names();
    load_passwords();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line shows debugger?

Comment: As I'm new to C++ I don't yet have a debugger, but I found out it happens on: `hash = crypt(line.c_str(), "");`

Comment: What does `line.c_str()` look like on the call to `crypt` ? Is it non-NULL ? Try adding `std::cout << "line: " << line.c_str() << std::endl;` immediately before the call to `crypt`. Also please note that if you're using `gcc` then you *do* have a debugger - it's called [gdb](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Egilpin/tutorial/).

Comment: Does specifying an actual string for the second parameter in the call to crypt() fix it?

Comment: @Meraj99 that actually fixed it, wow, thanks!

Comment: @Paradoxis: it's worth reading the [man page for crypt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt), since it specifies exactly what you need to pass for the second parameter (the salt).

Comment: @Paradoxis Oh, lol I just guessed. Anyways, you're welcome. I suppose I can post an answer for closure :3.

Comment: [The manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) says that the second parameter must be a 2 character string. It always pays to read the manual and check the return value for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to the call to crypt() (the salt) takes a string. You should pass a string having a minimum of 2 characters for it to work on (as in [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html)).
eg: `crypt(line.c_str(), "Any string here");`